# how do i get put a text after a button is pressed on a different window tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I tried to put the text in the function itself
it didn't say i was wrong but the program didn't show the text
does anyone know how to solve this?

```
import tkinter as tk

def life1():
    newwindow = tk.Toplevel(root)
    app.title("my biography")

    texto = Label(root, text ="hello")
root = tk.Tk()

button1 = tk.Button(app,text="my life",command=life1 , padx = 80, pady = 10, bg = "green")
```

Comment: You forgot to call `pack()` or `grid()` or `place()` on `texto` label.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `pack`, `place`, or `grid` on the `texto` label. If you want the label to show up in the new `Toplevel` window, the label needs to be a child of that window (eg: `Label(newwindow, ...)`).

Answer (score 0):

*First* of all, you have to add **root.mainloop()** at the end to stop the program, otherwise your program window would hang.

*Second*, to display the text you have to use **variable.pack()** so that it displays on the window.

*The third* and most important thing that everyone forgets is to capitalise the letter **L** in **tk.label**

```
`import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("first window")

def life1():
    root2 = tk.Toplevel(root)
    root2.title("my biography")

    texto = tk.Label(root2, text ="   hello    ")
    texto.pack()


button1 = tk.Button(root,text="my life",command=life1 , padx = 80, pady = 
10, bg = "green")
button1.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

`
For further queries kindly email awesomeansh03@gmail.com

Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand your third point. Where are they using `label` instead of `Label`?

Comment: It is predefined like that only. There is no particular reason.

Comment: What? Nothing is predefined as `label`. You made a claim that "everyone forgets to capitalize the letter L in tk.label" but the OP didn't do it and I've seen very little evidence of very many others doing it.